# driver build does not find orc_types.h; am I missing some ARCH type macro?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I have source code to a fiberoptic network card for which I'm trying to build the driver for Fedora 31 / 5.8.18 kernel.  The manufacture quit suppling updated Linux support after kernel 2.6.  I was able to get it running with Fedora 28 4.something kernel, but now need to get it running on a more contemporary version.

The driver build first compiles some of the kernel code at /usr/src/kernels/5.8...  Some code gets built but it fails when trying to compile scripts/sorttable.c, which includes sorttable.h, which includes <asm/orc_types.h>.  That last include is not found.

I searched the kernel source and found the file at /usr/src/kernels/5.8.../arch/x86/include/asm.  That leads me to believe I need the equivalent of a -I /usr/blah../arch/x86/include.  Or I'm missing some other fundamental truth of kernel building like I need a magical ARCH defined that points to that spot; and/or maybe its a setup of the compiler that I'm missing.

BTW, this **is** for x86 architecture, on an x86 machine.  I'm a little suprised I have to do anything, since its all native.

Anyone have some ideas or hints?

Unfortunately I'm not a Linux developer so I'm not so comfortable with all the automagic setup of the environment and where  come from by default and how to control those settings.

This is a fresh install of Fedora 31 where I've also done yum installs of kernel-devel, elfutils-libelf-devel, and gcc (although I only did the elfutils because I had notes that I had to do that for kernel 4 and don't remember why).

I also installed 'make' by just typing it on the command line and the OS volunteered to install it.  Same with 'flex' (? maybe that's a LEX tool??), and 'Bison', each of which were in the makefiles and caused me to do command line trick.

The makefiles for this driver are pretty complex

<edited: added that this is all for x86>

Comment: How do you know there isn't native support now?  What are the make and model ?

Comment: @stark I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe that's because I wasn't clear in my problem description (now edited). This is an i7 computer, so basically x86 architecture.  I'm confused why the kernel would not just compile without some intervention, but not being a Linux guy, I'm probably doing something wrong.  I wonder if I just need to add a link to the arch/x86 directory in the kernels/5.8... directory.  That seems unclean, and I probably need to modify one of the driver makefiles???

Comment: The main reason manufacturers stop supplying a Linux driver is that there is a better driver in the kernel source.  Not many network cards are unsupported so my guess is you don't need anything except maybe `make menuconfig`.

Comment: This is a pricy fiberoptic "reflective memory" type card (Scramnet).  We should move off it, or switch to Windows, since the manufacturer's Win driver works fine.